# Are variables in .h file global variables

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

There is a tim.h file with 5 int variables:int a;int b ;int c ;int d ;int e; .I am including tim.h in a myfile.c  file.

myfile.c has 4 functions: void func1();void func2();void func3() ;void func4();

Now i am including tim.h at the very start.

Now does a,b,c,d,e become global varibles and if I want 'a' to be local to func1() only should I define and declare 'a' in that function only and not in .h file?

getting multiple declaration errors between files.

Comment: Please don't describe your code - show it in a form of [mcve]

Comment: The general rule is not to define variables in header files. If you must reference them use `extern int a, b, c, d, e;`; define the variables in a single `.c` source file. To answer your objective question: Yes, define `a` inside the function to have a local variable (this definition may even *shadow* a previous global definition).

Comment: *"getting multiple declaration errors between files."*  Yes, if you include the header into several .c files, you get one copy of the variables in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are independent globals for each compilation unit in which the header is included.

You are getting the multiple declaration error because you are including the header file into multiple compilation units (or source *.c files). Every time you include the header file in a source file, the variables a,b,c,d,e get instantiated. This consequently leads to linking errors when your various compilation units all have identically named, **but distinct** variables.

You should try to reduce the variables scope as much as possible. If `a` is only required in func1() in source1.c, then declare `a` inside func1() as a `static int a;`. The static keyword will ensure that the variable keeps its value across func1() calls, as if it was a global:

```
void func1(void)
{
    static int a;
    ...
}
```